# onItemClick freeze in android ics

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I am having list view when i click on the list it moves to next activity and starts file

copying .But it is not displaying next activity's ui ,it is displaying only after file

copying finishes.Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to offload the file copying to an asynctask or similar. If you are doing the copy on the main thread then nothing else will execute until it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are copying in the UI tread and since UI thread is busy in copying so next activity can not be displayed till the copying is complete